# Nancy wont display any images

Tags: image, nancy

I'm just trying out Nancy for the first time. As it says on the documentation i just have to put my stuff under "Content/*" but no no avail. I get 404 when loading my own "splash.png"

```
<img src="~/Content/splash.png" /> -- NO
<img src="~/Content/nancy-logo.png" /> -- YES
```

I'm guessing this is a beginners pitfall but no one seems to talk about, maybe it's not a problem people normally get?

I've double checked my paths like 500 times.

I'm running under Visual Studio with the "Self Hosting and Razor" template project. Plz feel free to ask if u need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using self-hosting then my guess is that one of your images are set to different "copy to output directory". You need to make sure the static files are set to either "copy always" or "copy newer" or they won't be in the execution path of your application at runtime

Comment: Do i need to do that for everything i add into the project?

Comment: Only static content, when you self-host. It's because of what the application execution path is at runtime, i.e it moves into the \bin-folder at runtime so that will be your application root